# Make a GPS Lat/Long Lookup Table from Radolan Data in R, convert stereographic projection into lat long grid in R

Tags: r, geolocation, gps, geospatial, radolan

i´m using this example to load Radolan Data in R

[Example](http://moc.online.uni-marburg.de/doku.php?id=courses:bsc:project-thesis-geoei:lecture-notes:bdh:pt-ge-ln-bdh-01-9000),
[RADOLAN Specification](https://www.dwd.de/DE/leistungen/radolan/radolan_info/radolan_radvor_op_komposit_format_pdf.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=6)

```
 binary_filepath <- paste0("raa01-rw_10000-1708091950-dwd---bin")
    header_end <- regexpr("\003", readLines(binary_filepath, 1))

    rb_stream <- file(binary_filepath, "rb")
    skip_temp <- readBin(rb_stream, "raw", n = header_end, endian = "little")
    rb_data <- readBin(rb_stream, "raw", size = 1, n = 900*900*2, endian = "big")
    rb_data <- rawToBits(rb_data)

    rbi <- lapply(seq(0, 900*900-1, 1), function(x){
      sum(as.integer(rb_data[(x*16+1):(x*16+12)]) * 2**seq(0, 11, 1))
    })
    rbi <- unlist(rbi)
    rbi[1:16]
    rb <- raster(t(matrix(rbi, ncol = 900, nrow = 900)))
    rb <- flip(rb, "y")
    radolan_proj <- 
      CRS("+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=90 +lon_0=10 +k=0.93301270189 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370040 +b=6370040 +to_meter=1000 +no_defs")
    extent(rb) <- extent(-523.4622, 376.5378, -4658.645, -3758.645)
    projection(rb) <- radolan_proj
```

RADOLAN Data is a stereographic grid.
Each point in this grid is 1 KM Apart.

[image: 1 x 1 km-Raster]

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 900, 900, 810000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : -523.4622, 376.5378, -4658.645, -3758.645  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=90 +lon_0=10 +k=0.93301270189 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370040 +b=6370040 +to_meter=1000 +no_defs 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0, 2500  (min, max)
```

i wold like to make a Lat/Long lookup table for GPS Data.
How could i convert this rb Object to Lat/Long Grid?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `rb` object is a raster. If you want it with non-projected geographical coordinates (wgs84), you only need to reproject it:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(maps) # to add country limits 

# raster with Lat/Long non projected coordinates
rb_wgs84 <- projectRaster(rb, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
# Show the raster in a plot
plot(rb_wgs84)
maps::map("world", add = TRUE)
```

[image: Map in wgs84]

```
# Get coordinates and values in a dataframe
xyz <- data.frame(coordinates(rb_wgs84), z = values(rb_wgs84))
```

[image: Map data]

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes i´m searching for this conversion. But somehow the Value is getting lost or do i miss something?  > rb_wgs84[1:16]
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> rbi[1:16]
 [1] 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500  / the Z Value in the Frame you are creating is always an NA. I would like to be able to search for GPS coordinate in the Dataframe and read the Value.

Comment: The raster is a rectangular matrix. If you look at the projected raster in wgs84, you can see that the form does not look rectangular. This is because of the projection from stereoscopic. Some areas do not have values in the rectangular wgs84 because these are new positions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection for more information on projections. So in the final raster there are NA values, but as the figure suggests, there are also 0 and 2500 values. You can select them in the dataframe: `head(xyz[!is.na(xyz$z),])`.

Comment: Just a bonus tip but I am not sure what you want to achieve, you can use function `raster::extract` to get the z-value at a specific geographical position. You can use it on `rb_wgs84` if you have some gps coordinates from an external dataset: `raster::extract(rb_wgs84, mydata)`

Comment: Thank you. I would like to be able to see what radar value is at specific coordinate. SO for example i have Lat  is  48.77582 and Long  is  9.182987. I would like to be able to see what value the radar produced for that coordinate.